# How do i drop a webpart in sharepoint 2010 master page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to add a webpart to a sharepoint 2010 master page using SharePoint Designer. Is there a specific place we should add the webpart in the master page. I know this is not the right way but i have no option. I can write user control and delegate control but we need the webpart to be added in masterpage( please don't ask why??).

Any idea how to add the webpart and in which region.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not uncommon to have a web part in the master page. First you need to add a web part zone. SPD has ribbon buttons for that. Then you can insert the web part into the web part zone.

I'm not in front of SharePoint right now. I'll post a screenshot shortly.

Comment: How do you add a webpart zone to the master page?

Comment: @Jackson Use the ribbon buttons in SharePoint Designer. Insert ribbon > Web Part Zone.